# Possible to switch a large PHP backend from HTTP Auth to a session-based system?

Tags: php, authentication

I'm working to add a better authentication system to a mature backend site.  I've been using HTTP Authentication just because it's so easy to setup.  But as the site has grown, the downsides to this method have become more and more pronounced; specifically, the lack of security over standard HTTP connections, and the lack of a standard mechanism to log users out.

I've read over every PHP authentication question I can find on SO, but I still haven't found a satisfactory solution for upgrading a large existing codebase to use a session-based system.  The takeaway from most answers seems to be:

1. Don't roll your own if you don't know exactly what you're doing
2. Session-based authentication is a *really* involved subject

I have rolled my own user registration system before, and indeed, it seems woefully insecure looking at it now.  I can see it taking months to polish, when all I really want to be doing is working on the backend itself.

I imagine this is a very common problem.  Pretty much every website I've built has required at least a very minimal backend, and I think very few developers have the chops ("expertise") to build an airtight system.

I've looked at solutions using Zend Framework, CodeIgniter, and CakePHP — but they all presume a specific coding style (or so it seems), and the prospect of reorganizing all of my code is, in a word, deflating.  (And beyond that, the inefficiency of including one of these massive frameworks *just* for authentication really rubs me the wrong way.)

Is there a better solution?  Can I isolate the authentication class from one of these frameworks?  (Because this is just a backend site (closed), I don't need to worry about registration, or CAPTCHAS — or really any of the ancillary features of an authorization system.)

Thanks so much for your consideration.

Comment: FYI re Zend - you only need to use the Zend_Auth class - you don't need to pull in the whole lot. It's awesome like that.

Comment: Did not know that!  I'll admit I was scared off by the large scope of the ZF, but I'll have to give it another crack tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by Hamish's comment on my question, I learned that it's very easy to use the Zend_Auth class without having to use the rest of the framework, and without having created my project the "ZF way" — i.e., with the `zf` command line tool and the MVC pattern.

In the end, I only used Zend_Auth and Zend_Db.  I haven't integrated my proof of concept into my actual site yet, but I think it captures the basic functionality I was looking for.  All it does at the moment is cycle between the logged-in and logged-out states when the page is refreshed:

```
require_once('Zend/Db.php');
require_once('Zend/Auth.php');
require_once('Zend/Auth/Adapter/DbTable.php');
require_once('PasswordHash.php');
require_once('PasswordHash_Auth_Adapter_DbTable.php');

$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
    echo 'Logged in...';
    $auth->clearIdentity();
    echo 'logged out.';
} else {
    // authenticate
    echo 'Authenticating...';
    $db_options = parse_ini_file('../zend_db.ini');
    $db = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', $db_options);
    $authAdapter = new PasswordHash_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db);
    $authAdapter->setIdentity('test')->setCredential('test');
    $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
    if (!$result->isValid()) {
        echo 'invalid.';
    } else {
        echo 'valid.';
    }
}
```

`PasswordHash_Auth_Adapter_DbTable.php` is a custom Auth_Adapter_DbTable that uses [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) to obfuscate passwords, mostly copied from [an article by Jonathan Street](http://jonathanstreet.com/blog/adding-phpass-to-zend-framework).  I also found [an article by Alexander Peslyak](http://www.openwall.com/articles/PHP-Users-Passwords) (who I think is the creator of phpass) that was very helpful to understanding user/password storage broadly.

The `users` table is extremely bare-bones for the moment:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(3) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user` (`user`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

I inserted the one "test" user, with a phpass-generated hash for the password.  Ultimately I plan to have a login form that POSTs the user/password for authentication.  On the surface, this method (plain old POST form) seems insecure, but I looked at how Facebook's login form works, and indeed I can see my password in plaintext as part of the form data after logging in — so it can't be that insecure (right?).

Overall I'm very happy how simple this solution is... in a way it scares me how little I understand the actual nuts & bolts of Zend_Auth, but on the same token I'm glad it's tried & tested code (vs. rolling my own).

If I've made any egregious errors, please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible and can even be moderately straightforward. The key is that you need to isolate *all* security checks in as few places as possible, ideally in some common files. You really don't want to copy the same security-oriented code all over the place.

The structure of a session-based login system is basically three pieces:

1. The session setup
2. The security confirmation
3. The login page

The first two basically require you have a common set of files that *all* your pages include. Most projects have these; they do things like setup the database connection and load utility classes or functions. So somewhere in that, you need to add `session_start()`. Now you can use sessions (the `$_SESSION` superglobal).

Also in these common files and after the session is started, you need to check that the session says the user is logged in (and who has). If they are, then you can setup whatever global structures that all pages need to work with the current login.

If the session says they are not logged in, the common files need to hijack the page request and redirect the user to a login page. This login page can and should use the common structure, but it needs to set a control variable to bypass the security check, because the user is (obviously) not logged in. You need to do the same thing to process the POST from the login screen which is where you do the boring password checks, setup the session to say they're logged in and redirect either to a default page or whichever page they were trying to go to.

Comment: Luckily the structure of this backend is already setup so all resources (pages) are loaded through a root "engine" page — so I don't think I'd have to change much.

Comment: That's a big bonus. That means the worst you have to watch out for is the odd rogue page that check to see the request is HTTP Authed.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP authentication is **not** insecure over unencrypted connections as long as you're using the digest method. That said, the nonexistence of a logout mechanism is a serious downside and, together with minimal user-agent implemented interface for entering the credentials are the main reasons it's not used for user-facing pages.

In your case -- a backend service --, moving from a simple stateless mechanism to a session-based one is much less compelling (there's typically no need for "logout" functionality), and I would recommend against it unless the authentication were very expensive on the server-side.

If you want your service to be used by third-parties without the user providing his credentials to that third party, HTTP authentication is of course insufficient (though it could be still be used for the authentication part), but it also requires more complicated approaches (like OAuth) that I think don't fit in what you're thinking when you say "session-based system".

Comment: Yeah, "session-based" was deliberately vague because I wasn't confident how to describe it.  But I was imagining a setup where there are salted + encrypted passwords stored in a database... and upon authenticating, a session or cookie would track the "logged in" status.  Very interesting Re: digest vs. basic HTTP auth — I wasn't aware of the distinction.

Comment: @JKS You are confusing things. One thing is how the authentication is done -- how the server requests the credentials, how the client provides them, and how the server responds back -- either resulting in the resource requested for (in case of HTTP auth) or some token (e.g. a session id) that the client can then use to be authorized to access the restricted resources (e.g. session based). How the credentials are stored, be it in a txt file, a database, whatever is another matter -- you can use HTTP auth backed by a database, and Apache comes with modules to do just that.

Comment: Sorry to confuse things... I mean there are two practical "strategies" available to me — one where Apache does all of the legwork, and the other (which I've called "session-based") where I have to implement both the user/password storage and the authentication mechanism.  I'm not sure how best to describe this 2nd strategy.